# discord.py exception when creating channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

When i tried to create channel, i got that error:

```
Ignoring exception in command gt:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/spm_lottery_bot/bot.py", line 81, in gt
    c = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f"ticket-#{ticket.number}", position=ticket.number - 1, 
overwrites=overwrites, category=category)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 893, in create_text_channel
    data = await self._create_channel(name, overwrites, ChannelType.text, category, reason=reason, 
**options)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 796, in _create_channel
    'id': target.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

How can i fix that?
Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def gt(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    guild = bot.get_guild(749343108969398332)
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=749741704038449295)
    for ticket in ticket_list:
        print(ticket.owner_discord)
        c = None
        role = guild.get_role(749399259719401544)
        overwrites = {
            role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            guild.get_member_named(ticket.owner_discord): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
        }
        x = gen_stickers(int(ticket.win_summ), guild, printable=True)
        c = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f"билет-#{ticket.number}", position=ticket.number - 1, overwrites=overwrites, category=category,reason='билетик')
        id = guild.get_member_named(ticket.owner_discord)

        await c.send(content=f'<@{id.id}> -- '+x)

        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
```

On the second for loop iteration it gives error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Please include at least a snippet of your code.

Comment: i just create channel

Comment: please include the whole command/event code, where you get role or member and where you make overwrites

Comment: its a command  .

Comment: I am having the same issue right now. From what I can tell my channel object has a .id value so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Banana can we see ticket_list pls

Comment: also try printing guild.get_member_named(ticket.owner_discord.id) above and see if you get the same error or a new one. that maybe an issue

Comment: oh it crashes on russian name

Comment: how can i fix that? @rpgstar

Comment: Is there a reason why you are storing the user's Discord name instead of their userid? This way it won't crash on Russian names, and it won't stop working when people change their name either.

Comment: @banana yea make it store user ID... two people may have the same name but no two people have the same id

Comment: yes i will use user id, but i'm wondering if I can get member named russian, is it possible?

Comment: bruh same error with user id's

Comment: @rpgstar help :/